# Android WebView links touch area

Tags: android, webview, hyperlink

I have a WebView containing a few clickable links. 
Is there a way to increase the touch area of those links as it may be rather difficult to tap on the links and open them, even though they are visually large enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the **`zoom`** property.

```
WebView yourwebview = (WebView) findViewByID(R.Layout.id.webview1);
yourwebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
yourwebview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```